# Getting permission issue while installing HDP 2.0 in windows 8.1

Tags: windows, hadoop

Im getting following error while installing hortonworks data platform on windows 8.1.

To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or use the microsoft net framework configuration tool.

Application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy

See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

******* *Exception Text* *********
System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name, Boolean writable)
   at System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(String variable, String value, EnvironmentVariableTarget target)
   at GUI.forma.Generate_Cluster_props(String path, String mode)
   at GUI.forma.Validate_fields(String mode, String path)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer

******* *Loaded Assemblies* *********
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34003 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR

### CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll

GUI
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0

### CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/suren/AppData/Local/Temp/MSIE3D.tmp

System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll

System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll

System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34003 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll

System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll

******* *JIT Debugging* *********
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Did you solved the above error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Open a command prompt with Administrator privileges and execute the MSI installer command. Example below:
msiexec /lv c:\hdplog.txt /i "C:\Users\soumikhere\Downloads\hdp-2.0.6-GA\hdp-2.0.6.0.winpkg.msi"

The exact error will come in c:\hdplog.txt. I hope you got the pre-requisites covered. If not please ensure that you have installed Java (jdk1.6.0_31 or above) and Python installed and the necessary Java_Home and Path variable is set (Path should contain Python home).

Regards
Soumik